# Wordpress get_theme_mod in custom.css.php file not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, stylesheet

In Wordpress Theme development, I am enqueuing a colors.php file which is acting as a stylesheet.

```
wp_register_style( 'custom_colors', $uri . '/assets/css/colors.php', [], $ver );

wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_colors' );
```

I have created a wordpress customizer section and setting to manage the colors. I have added my setting in the customizer like so:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'primary_color', [
    'default'       =>  '#1ABC9C'
]);

$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Color_Control( 
        $wp_customize, 
        'primary_color_input', 
        array(
            'label'      => __( 'Primary Accent Color', 'myslug' ),
            'section'    => 'color_section',
            'settings'   => 'primary_color',
        )
    ) 
);
```

When I call get_theme_mod directly in the header.php file as a test to echo out the value it works:

```
$color = get_theme_mod('primary_color', '#1ABC9C'); //hex color is default
echo $color;
```

But when I call the same line in my colors.php file I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_theme_mods() in /app/public/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/css/colors.php:28
```

I want to use the get_them_mod value to update all link colors in my colors.php file instead of dynamically printing out style sin the head.

Can anyone please help me understand what is going wrong here?

This in my colors.php file:

```
header("content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

$color = get_theme_mod('primary_color', '#1ABC9C'); 

a { color: <?php echo $color; ?>; }
```

Comment: you might need to include `wp-includes/theme.php.` first in your css/php file

Comment: like `<?php
require_once("../howevermanytimes../../wp-load.php");
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_theme_mod' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-includes/theme.php.' );
}`

Comment: Hey Stender that worked perfectly! Thank you so much! Can you put it as answer and if possible, can you explain to me what including those files have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `get_theme_mods` (along with all the other style related functions) is found inside `wp-includes/theme.php`

When you are creating custom files, but still need wordpress functions, you should tell wordpress to load first. this is done by `require_once("../howevermanytimes../../wp-load.php")`

after that, you can test if the function that you need, or any function in that file, exists. in this example, it is done by calling

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_theme_mod' ) ) { 
    require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-includes/theme.php.' ); 
}
```

This makes sure, that the functions are loaded.

The same could be done with all the other function files,

So another example could be :

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_post_meta' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/post.php' );
}
```

which would give you access to functions like `post_exists()` etc.

Comment: Excellent and informative information! Thank you for your kind help on this issue, I really appreciate it.